# Function removeAttributeSearch

Tags: magento2, collection

I have a code:

```
$productCollectionClone = $productCollection->getCollectionClone();
$collection = $productCollectionClone->removeAttributeSearch($attribute->getAttributeCode());
```

Anyone can help me explain how the function removeAttributeSearch work?

Comment: This is not a default Magento function. It seems you are using mageplaza layered navigation extension. Can you please confirm ?

Comment: Yes, You're right. Thank you. I have a bug with Magento 2.3.2. Call to undefined method Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::getCollectionClone(). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: It seems the Fulltext Search Model is not properly overriden, because its trying to call `getCollectionClone()` on core module and its not part of core functionality. Have you added this module recently ?

Comment: Yes, I have installed this module. When I try to filter, I get this issue.

Comment: Hello, @AbdulPathan did you found solution?

Comment: Hey there, duplicate question from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293847/uncaught-error-call-to-undefined-method-magento-2-3-3 where I believe a friendly folk posted the solution to your question ;-)