# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method - Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, php-7.3

I tried find a solution to this magento 2 theme problem. How should be edit the theme file?

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor::getCollectionClone() in app/code/custom_theme/LayeredAjax/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml:15
Stack trace:
#0 vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include()
#1 vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(271): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer\Interceptor), '/home/npartsco/...', Array)
#2 vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(301): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/home/npartsco/...')
#3 vendor/magento/module-layered-navigation/Block/Navigation/FilterRenderer.php(29): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#4 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Mage in app/code/custom_theme/LayeredAjax/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml on line 15
```

line 12-23

```
<?php
    $productCollection = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
    $productCollectionClone = $productCollection->getCollectionClone();
    $collection = $productCollectionClone
        ->removeAttributeSearch(['price.from', 'price.to']);

    $min = $collection->getMinPrice();
    $max = $collection->getMaxPrice();

    list($from, $to) = $requestValue ? explode('-', $requestValue) : [$min, $max];
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't understand why do you want clone of your collection. But still you can try php [object cloning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)

Instead of which is I guess not available in Magento:

```
$productCollection = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
$productCollectionClone = $productCollection->getCollectionClone();
```

Try this one:

```
$productCollection = $filter->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
$productCollectionClone = clone $productCollection;
```

Comment: Thanks it works! I don't know how it doesn't works with magento 2.3.3 and php 7.3 now because earlier was magento 2.2.6 and php 7.2 then all works.

Comment: @ShoaibMunir after add this solution still, I can't get my custom filter in layered navigation. Do you know solution for that?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/2ELZjO it's di.xml file code.

Comment: https://codeshare.io/aJ4rVr It's fulltext collection file of custom module. There are functions code available also. But, I didn't add here.

Comment: Note : I enabled elasticsearch 5+ version for catalog search from configuration.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that for some reason, the product collection class

```
\Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
```

is not overrided by the the one from Mageplaza

```
Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection
```

which is containing the methods not found **getCollectionClone()**, **removeAttributeSearch()**, etc

In our case, it seems to be related to the fact that we use **ElasticSearch7** on Magento 2.4.1. The **di.xml** file from **Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation** is only set up for **ElasticSearch6**.

The proper way to fix it would be to create a custom module to add the missing configuration, but here is a quick fix explaining what to do.
Up to you to implement it the way it suits you.

So you want to edit / override this file...

**app/code/Mageplaza/LayeredNavigation/etc/di.xml**

... and basically just duplicate and edit every block from this :

```
<arguments>
  <argument name="factories" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="elasticsearch6" xsi:type="object">Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory</item>
  </argument>
</arguments>
```

to this :

```
<arguments>
  <argument name="factories" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="elasticsearch6" xsi:type="object">Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory</item>
    <item name="elasticsearch7" xsi:type="object">Mageplaza\LayeredNavigation\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\CollectionFactory</item>
  </argument>
</arguments>
```

Hope it can help someone ;-)

Comment: if it's just one file change, Can you please share your whole di.xml file

Comment: They did an upgrade of the extension, solving this ;-)

Comment: I have created by changing some things in this. So can't get their upgrade. That's why I am asking for the file. https://github.com/NikZh/magento2-multiple-layered-navigation

Comment: https://pastebin.com/WH2jZmnX

Comment: oh that's more changes. I am able to filter one time now. But multiple filter isn't working. Showing so many errors. Like `{"0":"Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.","1":"
#1 Magento\\Framework\\Data\\Collection\\AbstractDb->_renderFilters() called at [app\\code\\[Vendor]\\LayeredNavigation\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection.php:391]\n`
... and so on... Let me know if you can help in any way. My module works fine in Magento 2.3.2 with search engine MYSQL. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this is errors with version php
example php 7.3 can not use clone ('clone $productCollection;')

and php 7.2 can use it